# Simple math calculation with SQLite - Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm fairly new to SQL, and i'm trying to make a query with simple math in the Android app.
Here's what i'm trying to do -

I have a table named allfoods, with columns named 'calories' and 'size'. Here's the query-

```
int tempCalories = 100;
int maxCalories = 300;
Cursor dataFoods = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM allfoods WHERE size <> 0 AND (" + tempCalories + " + (calories * (size / 100)) < " + maxCalories +")" , null);
```

Will that work?
I have some trouble testing it myself, since the returned values are too varied.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familliar with SQLite but your SQL syntax seems fine. I'm not familliar with SQL tables and variables neither, so fix me if I'm wrong, but if 'size < 100' and size is integer, wouldn't 'size/100 = 0'? This may cause the return values to be so varied.

Comment: You're absolutely right.I've figured it out 30 minutes after I have posted the question.The syntax should be '(size / 100.0)'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hello tofira**,

**Yes**, your query will work, if you change the denominator to *100.0* in `(size / 100.0)`.

However, your query might return 0, as your equation:

`100  + (calories * (size / 100.0)) < 300`

will return false when the values for size and/or calories are out of range.

## Proof

To test your query I created a table with data, and a tests view.

### Data

To have something to test against, I created a table where the values for size ranged in steps of 1 from 1 to 1000 and calories ranged in steps of 5 from 5 to 5000, like this:

```
Id  |   size    |   calories
----------------------------
1   |   1       |   5
2   |   2       |   10
3   |   3       |   15
4   |   4       |   20
5   |   5       |   25
```

### Test

To test your equation, I created a view to verify each step of your equation.

#### SQL

```
CREATE VIEW "test" AS 
    SELECT id, size AS 'S', calories AS 'C',
    size/100.0 AS 'S/100',
    calories * (size/100.0) AS 'C*(S/100)', 
    100 + (calories * (size/100.0)) AS '100+(C*(S/100))',
    CASE WHEN (300 > (100 + (calories * (size/100.0)))) 
        THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS 'Eq'
    FROM allfoods;
```

#### Result

```
Id  |  S   |  C    |  S/100  |  C*(S/100)  |  100+(C*(S/100))  |  Eq
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
62  |  62  |  310  |  0.62   |  192.2      |  292.2            |  true
63  |  63  |  315  |  0.63   |  198.45     |  298.45           |  true
64  |  64  |  320  |  0.64   |  204.8      |  304.8            |  false
65  |  65  |  325  |  0.65   |  211.25     |  311.25           |  false
66  |  66  |  330  |  0.66   |  217.8      |  317.8            |  false
```

### Conclusion

Running your query against my test data would return row 1 to 63.

Comment: +1 I would give even two upvotes if I could just for your effort ;-) good work